# How do you explicitly form the dual of the Yoneda lemma?

Tags: category-theory

I'm self learning Category theory from Mac Lane's Category theory, and I'm trying to find the dual statement of the Yoneda lemma:

> For every $K : D \rightarrow \text{Set} $ that is locally small and for every $r \in D$, there exists a bijection $y : \text{Nat}(D(r, -), K) \cong Kr$ by $\alpha : D(r, -) \rightarrow K \mapsto \alpha_r 1_r$.

I'm having trouble understanding the concept of duality and how I would take the dual of this.  **Can someone EXPLICITLY explain the steps of how they would take the dual of this statement?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any category comes naturally equipped with two distinct functors into $\text{Set}$: there is the covariant functor $h^r\colon a\mapsto\text{Hom}(r,a)$ and the contravariant functor $h_r\colon a\mapsto\text{Hom}(a,r).$ There is a duality between them, in the sense that $h_r$ for the category $D$ is $h^r$ on $D^\text{op}.$ Turning the arrows around changes $D$ into $D^\text{op}$ and $h_r$ into $h^r$.

So to each object we can associate a presheaf or a co-presheaf. The covariant and contravariant Yoneda lemmas tell us that both associations are embeddings:

1. if $K$ is a covariant functor $D\to \text{Set}$, then we have the natural isomorphism $\text{Hom}(D(r,-),K)\cong K(r)$, with the isomorphism given by $\alpha\mapsto \alpha_r(1_r).$
2. if $K$ is a contravariant functor $D\to \text{Set}$, then we have the natural isomorphism $\text{Hom}(D(-,r),K)\cong K(r),$ with the isomorphism given by $\alpha\mapsto \alpha_r(1_r).$

To be even more explicit, let us note that the covariant Yoneda lemma applies to any category. In particular, if you turn the arrows around of $D$, you get the dual category $D^\text{op}$, which has $D^\text{op}(r,s)=D(s,r)$. If $f\colon s\to r$ is an arrow in $D$, then $f^\text{op}\colon r\to s$ is an arrow in $D^\text{op}.$

Now let's apply the Yoneda lemma to this category $D^\text{op}$. If $K$ is a covariant functor $D^\text{op}\to\text{Set},$ then we have $\text{Hom}(D^\text{op}(r,-),K)=\text{Hom}(D(-,r),K)\cong K(r).$ But a covariant functor $D^\text{op}\to\text{Set}$ is nothing but a contravariant functor $D\to\text{Set}.$ Thus we see that the contravariant Yoneda lemma is nothing but the covariant Yoneda lemma applied to the category $D$ with its arrows reversed.

---

So the covariant and contravariant Yoneda lemmas are dual in the sense that they are identical theorems, states for two categories which are dual to one another. But another way to get dual statements in category theory is to dualize everything in sight. Every line of the theorem. Any statement in the language of category theorem has an equivalent dual statement. For example, the statement that $A\times(B+C)\cong A\times B+A\times C$ is a natural isomorphism (which holds in any distributive category) has a dual statement $A + (B\times C)\cong (A+B)\times(A + C).$ We turn all limits into colimits.

To achieve this for the Yoneda lemma, let's not just replace $D$ by its opposite, but also $\text{Set}$ by its opposite, and turn all products into coproducts, etc.

This is called the [co-Yoneda lemma](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/co-Yoneda+lemma), which states that $$\int^{r\in D}D(r,s)\times K(r)\cong K(s)$$ (and also comes in a contravariant version), and is the formal dual of the Yoneda lemma, in the sense that the coend is the dual limit of the end, and tensor product is the dual of hom.

To go into a bit more detail on this, note that the set of functions between two sets $\text{Hom}(S,T)$ is isomorphic to a product $T^S=\displaystyle\prod_{s\in S}T.$ Products admit categorical descriptions in terms of universal properties, and as such they have duals, calls disjoint unions, or sums, formed by reversing the arrows in the universal diagram.

The dual of the weighted product $\displaystyle\prod_{s\in D}K(r)^{D(s,r)}$ is the weighted sum $\displaystyle\sum_{s\in D}D(s,r)\times K(r).$

The covariant Yoneda lemma says that two functors $D\times \text{Set}^D\to\text{Set}$ are isomorphic, the two functors being "take hom, i.e. weighted product" $(r,K)\mapsto \text{Hom}(h^r,K)$ and "evaluate" $(r,K)\mapsto K(r)$. The contravariant Yoneda lemma says the same thing about the two functors $D^\text{op}\times \text{Set}^{D^\text{op}}\to\text{Set}.$

Dualizing literally everything in sight, we have isomorphism of two functors $D^\text{op}\times (\text{Set}^\text{op})^{D^\text{op}}\to\text{Set}^\text{op}$ and of two functors $D\times (\text{Set}^\text{op})^{D}\to\text{Set}^\text{op}.$ Weighted products in $\text{Set}^\text{op}$ are weighted sums in $\text{Set},$ therefore these isomorphisms are the co-Yoneda lemma. Instead of taking the dual of our starting category, we take the dual of the functor category in which the isomorphisms live.

Comment: Can you explicitly explain how you formed the dual of the Yoneda lemma?  What did you do to each part of the Yoneda lemma that resulted in leaving everything the same except for the functor $D(-, r)$?  And how is the bijective map defined in the dual?

Comment: @OliverG the map implementing the natural isomorphism for the covariant and contravariant Yoneda lemmas is essentially the same. But I added some text making that explicit, and explaining how to view them as dual. Is it better?

Comment: I still don't understand what you did to the covariant Yonenda lemma to get it's dual (are you now saying the dual of the Yoneda lemma is the contravariant Yoneda lemma?).  What did you do to each part of the definition of the Yoneda lemma to determine how it would be altered to be part of the "dual" Yoneda lemma?  By what "duality criterion" did you know to change the covariant functor $K: D \rightarrow \text{Set}$ to a contravariant functor $K: D \rightarrow \text{Set}$ and Nat$(D(r, -) , K)$ to Nat$(D(-, r), K)$?

Comment: @OliverG to get the contravariant Yoneda lemma from the covariant, you simply reverse all arrows. I added a new paragraph to make this very explicit. Is it clearer now?

Comment: So to find the dual of the Yoneda lemma, you applied the Yoneda lemma to the opposite of the free variables $D, r$?

Comment: @OliverG I can't quite understand the phrasing of your question. "opposite" is something you do to categories or arrows, not really variables or objects...

Comment: @OliverG but to attempt to answer, I applied the Yoneda lemma to the opposite category of $D$, which has the same objects, but arrows pointing in the opposite direction to $D$.

Comment: I think I'm understanding, but to make sure:  Why does applying the lemma to the opposite category of $D$ yield the dual of the lemma?

Comment: @OliverG Switching from $D$ to $D^\text{op}$ means switching from $D(-,r)$ to $D(r,-)$. And that is the only difference between the two lemmas; one uses the contravariant hom-functors and one uses the covariant.

Comment: @OliverG I added some more explication about the co-Yoneda lemma too, and the sense in which it is a dual. You haven't targeted any questions to that part of my answer, perhaps because you are not familiar with ends/coends? Maybe if I say it in terms of weighted sums/products it will seem more understandable.

Comment: I haven't asked any questions about ends/coends because those concepts have not been covered yet in the Mac Lane's category (of which I am on page 62).  But I think I understand now the basic concept of finding the dual:  substitute the opposite categories in for the "variables" in question and evaluate the expression.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @OliverG right, that's why I rephrased the end/coend business in terms of products/sums. But ok. Yes, substitute opposite category is how we get dual.